# Module pattern - separation of concerns - encapsulation in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module

I am about to rewrite an app (it is in vanilla JS originally) in ES6, in which module patter is apllied.

In no time, at the beginning I realized that I am struggling to get 'separation of concerns' done since if we are about to apply data privacy in ES6 we only use "{}" but not IIFE's as in case of vanilla JS (which as known are practically function expressions).

**Vanilla JS solution:**

```
var budgetController = (function() {

    const x = 20;

    function add(a) {
        return x + a;
    }   

    return {
        getSum: function(b){
            console.log(add(b));
        } 
    }
})();



UIController = (function() {

    // some code

})();



Controller = (function(BudgetCrtl, UICtrl) {

    var n = BudgetCrtl.getSum(3);
    console.log(n);

})(budgetController, UIController);
```

In ES6 I attemted to use simply func expressions not IIFE's in order to pass the other modul in the controller modul and be able to use/pass over the public methods but it dod not work.

**ES6 attempt:**

```
let budgetController = function() {
    const x = 20;
    function add(a) {
        return x + a;
    }   
    return {
        getSum: (b) => console.log(add(b))
    }
}



UIController = function() {
    // some code
}



Controller = function(BudgetCrtl, UICtrl) {
    const n = BudgetCrtl.getSum();
    console.log(n);
}
Controller(budgetController, UIController);
```

Could anyone provide me with some solution to involve somehow in ES6 the so called encapsulation and above mentioned things? Any idea would be appreciated!
Cheers, thank you!

Comment: in vanilla JS (ES5) version, `budgetController` is `{
        getSum: (b) => console.log(add(b))
    }` ... in ES6 version, `budgetController` is exactly the whole function you made it to be ... so, completely different thing

Comment: Encapsulation using IIFEs did not change from ES5 to ES6. Why would you drop the function invocations? Now your "modules" became functions, and of course it doesn't work any more.

Comment: Would not drop, I was just curious if there was any update on this. in ES6 with '{..}' you can achieve data privacy but cannot pass any args and since no parameters can be passed in to the 'controller module' this way we are unable to apply module pattern. (If I am rigth.) So, that is why I attempted a workaround to use functions as in their body a brandnew block is created, and data privacy as well (ES6 var's are block scoped). Along the way, the thing that passed my attention is that an IIFE is called rigth away unlike a function which needs to be called first. (Inattentivenes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute that `BudgetCrtl` to get access to the `getSum` function like so `BudgetCrtl().getSum(3)`, since that `BudgetCrtl` is a function and not
 a value returned from it's execution .

plus if you want the value to be stored to the n you should not console.log in the arrow function immediately, because the way it is now it's implicitly returning `undefined`

```js
let budgetController = function() {
    const x = 20;
    function add(a) {
        return x + a;
    }   
    return {
        getSum: (b) => {
          let newVal = add(b)

          console.log(newVal)

          return newVal // so that you can store the value in `n`
        }
    }
}



UIController = function() {
    // some code
}



Controller = function(BudgetCrtl, UICtrl) {
    const n = BudgetCrtl().getSum(3);
    console.log(n);
}
Controller(budgetController, UIController);
```

Comment: Ohh, yes got it! Thank you!